# Plotting the row cells across the column cells in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, plot, regression, anova

I have a 2 x 3 matrix called `a`. I was wondering if there is a way I could plot this matrix such that I could see how the values of row cells (`"m"` and `"f"`) change across the column cells (`"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`)?

A conceptual form of the desired plot is shown in the picture below.

(***Note:*** I guess the idea is very similar to how `interaction.plot()` works)

**Here is what I have tried with no success:**

```
a = matrix(c(15,14, 16,40, 42,41), nrow = 2, dimnames = list(A = c("m", "f"), B = c("a", "b", "c")))
plot(a, xaxt = "n", ylab = "Scores", xlab = "B")
g = axTicks(1)
n = length(colnames(a))
u = diff(range(g))/n
d = seq(min(g), max(g), len = n)
axis(1, at = d, lab = dimnames(a)[[2]], font = 2)
lines(a[1,], a[2,])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this???

```
a = matrix(c(15,14, 16,40, 42,41), nrow = 2, 
      dimnames = list(A = c("m", "f"), B = c("a", "b", "c")))
matplot(t(a), type = "b", pch=19, xaxt="n")
axis(1, at = 1:ncol(a), labels = colnames(a))
```

Comment: Because that is how `matplot` is written to behave

Comment: `matplot` works without transposing (as an exercise remove the `t` and see what happens). It's just that you do not get the desired result (to me "not working" means a the function call threw an error). The reason matplot traverses columns instead of rows, is likely because in R, columns generally represent variables while rows represent observations.  Normally, we want to plot variables instead of an observation.